# System.NullReferenceException on a ForEach of a datagrid

Tags: vb.net

So all is in the question, I have a datagrid view who's parcoured by a foreach in his rows collection like so `dataGridView1.Rows` and I get and error of null type in the second if of the for each

```
Sub DataColumnFirstDouble(ByRef dGridView As DataGridView, ByVal iCol As Integer)

    Dim bFirstRow As Boolean = False
    Dim sTemp As String = ""

    For Each RW As DataGridViewRow In dGridView.Rows

        If (bFirstRow) Then
            If (RW.Cells(iCol).Value.ToString() = sTemp) Then
                RW.Cells(iCol).Selected = True
                dGridView.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                dGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If

        sTemp = RW.Cells(iCol).Value.ToString()
        bFirstRow = True

    Next

End Sub
```

By the way the Datagrid is populated with 1 entry going

```
LongString, Number, Number

Hello     , 8     , 8
```

The bug occur when I click on a new row also the function is called on the event of row leave

Need some help

By the way what I try to do is to check when the user enter the name in the longstring space who's a primary unique key in a database but It seems I can't find anythings to handle it by vb so I try to parse it every times he leave the rows to check if there's any double

Comment: So the name of your sub-routine is `Double`?

Comment: I just edited it, it was only to make sense because in my code the function name seems to make no sense if you don't have all the code but no it's no double ^^'' let me correct that

Comment: When you debug this, what actual value is `null`?  I would guess that `RW.Cells(iCol)` isn't finding anything.  Maybe the first iteration of the rows is a header row and doesn't have the columns you expect?

Comment: @Mokmeuh - are you serious, you have not debugged this before posting your question? The first thing you should do when you get a `NullReferenceException` is to debug and find out which exact line and object is `null`.

Comment: @KarlAnderson

`DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value` As expected return `Hello` 

And I know where is the null value I jsut don't know how to fix it

By the way if you need to know who's obvious the null value is the new row who's created automaticly when the previous row as been filled up

Comment: @David You seems the only one who's willing to help me so yea it's the second iteration of RW.Cells(iCol) who's null wich is the new empty row created when the last one have something inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear where the error is, you should debug to figure out which variable exactly is null. So I'll assume it's `RW.Cells(iCol).Value`.

If there's no value in the cell, it might be null. This mean `ToString` won't work.

```
    If (bFirstRow) Then
        If RW.Cells(iCol).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso RW.Cells(iCol).Value.ToString() = sTemp Then
            RW.Cells(iCol).Selected = True
            dGridView.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            dGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If
    End If
```

You could even check if `RW.Cells(iCol)` exists, maybe it's trying to fetch the data in a cell that doesn't exists in the row.

Comment: Ok thankcx yes it's the RW.Cells(iCol).Value at the second row index 1 wich is null since it's a new row but anyways I've fixed it with setting a primary key so I doN,t have to find it